# how to calculate percentage for nested fields in ruby on rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, nested, field

I have set default 3 nested attributes fields when page loads in controller

```
def new
@candidate = Candidate.new
#@candidate.educations.build
3.times do
  education = @candidate.educations.build
end
```

end
I am calculating percentage for nested fields using jquery in my candidates.coffee files i have

```
$('#max_marks, #marks_obtained').keyup ->
max_marks = parseFloat($('#max_marks').val()) or 0
marks_obtained = parseFloat($('#marks_obtained').val()) or 0
$('#percentage').val marks_obtained * 100 / max_marks
return
```

In _education_fields.html.erb i have my fields

```
 <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :max_marks %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :max_marks, id: 'max_marks' %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :marks_obtained %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :marks_obtained, id: 'marks_obtained'%>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :percentage %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :percentage, id: 'percentage' %>
    </div>
```

Now i am able to calculate percentage for first field but second and third field i am not able to apply jquery because id's are same for 3 fields how do i calculate percentage for other 2 fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is `child_index` thing that rails provide in nested association when using in html.erb.

Below code may resolve your problem.

```
<div class="education_<%= f.options[:child_index] %>">
  <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :max_marks %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :max_marks, class: 'max_marks', data: {index: f.options[:child_index]} %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :marks_obtained %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :marks_obtained, class: 'marks_obtained', data: {index: f.options[:child_index]}%>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :percentage %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :percentage, class: 'percentage' %>
    </div>
</div>



$('.max_marks, .marks_obtained').focusout(function(event){
      var target = $(event.target), parent = target.parents().find('.education_' + target.attr('data-index'));
      if (parseInt(parent.find('.marks_obtained').val()) > parseInt(parent.find('.max_marks').val())){
         alert('Marks Obtained cannot be greater then Maximun Marks');
         parent.find('.marks_obtained').val('');
      } else {
        var max_marks = parseFloat(parent.find('.max_marks').val())
        var marks_obtained = parseFloat(parent.find('.marks_obtained').val())

max_marks = max_marks === NaN ? 0 : max_marks

marks_obtained = marks_obtained === NaN ? 0 : marks_obtained
        parent.find('.percentage').val(marks_obtained * 100 / max_marks)
      }
    });
```

Comment: when i enter max marks & marks obtained it is not calculating percentage, getting error like "target.attribute is not a function". Not working

Comment: and i am getting "SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list" this error.

Comment: how to add if condition to this to check if marks_obtained should be less then max_marks

Comment: if parseInt($('.marks_obtained').val()) > parseInt($('.max_marks').val())
      alert 'Marks Obtained cannot be greater then Maximun Marks'
    else
      parent.find('.percentage').val marks_obtained * 100 / max_marks                                                           i added this code but this code will give alert for only 1st field not working for other two fields.

Comment: **parseInt($('.marks_obtained').val()) > parseInt($('.max_marks').val())**
This condition is causing the issue. **$('.marks_obtained')** will select first element specified by JQuery selector.

I have updated the Jquery Code. This may help you.

Comment: how do i remove NaN in percentage field. if i remove numbers it will display NaN in percentage field.

Comment: You need to check that parseFloat returning a valid number or NaN. If it is returning NaN convert that into 0. See updated jquery code in answer.